Suggestions on how to clean an old bench vise
I'm finally getting around to building my own work bench and I want to give my dad's old bench vise a new lease on life. Everything works fine but it has a lot of old paint and other gunk all over that I'd like to clean off as best I can.
Any suggestions on what to use that won't harm the metal? Should I scrape it all and try to repaint? Mineral spirits? Others?



As old tools go, that's remarkably clean.

Just my opinion...I wouldn't touch it.   Everything on it tells a story.  Maybe a little oil on the screw.

If you must clean it, get some paint stripper for the obvious paint. To remove any rust brush or soak in vinegar or brush on naval jelly for 10 to 20 minutes, wipe or brush off and dry completely. Prime and paint the base fire engine red, just kidding, pick your color. Put a lite coating of oil on the moving parts and threads. Be prepared to curse when you scratch your new finish because it will happen.

Haha I hears the chorus of groans about cleaning and I promise, I'll only clean superficially. Thanks for the tips.

If you must clean it, try hitting it with some paint stripper, then a power washer.  Dry it right away, then hit the screws with some oil.
